# How do i setup a jenkins job that calls another jenkins job in parallel but with an array as a parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I want to build a jenkins job, say Job A. I have another Jenkins Deploy Job, say Job B.
I have an aws cli command that gets me the names of ECS services under a particular cluster, i put that in an array. 
Now, for Each Element of the array as parameter, i want to Call Job B.
i.e I want to have Job A to invoke Job B in Parallel, for each element of the array, i pass to it as parameter.

New to jenkins so tried using "Multi-Job Plugin" and "Parameterized Plugin"

```
    pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Run JobB') {
            steps {
                script{
                    def ecs_services = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']
                    for (int i = 0; i < ecs_services.size(); i++) {
                        def service = ecs_services[i]
                        ecs["${service}"] = build job: 'JobB' , parameters: [name: 'foo', value: 'bar']
                    }
                    failFast: true
                    parallel ecs
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

something  as simple as, also errors out

    pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello world!' 
            }
        }
     }
    }




Started by user ops
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 2: Invalid argument for agent - '${any}' - must be map of config options or bare none. @ line 2, column 11.
       agent any 
             ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:410)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:373)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:213)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in a jenkins pipeline script of JobA:

```
pipeline {
        agent {
            node {
                label "master"  //change this as per your agent label
            }
        }
    stages {
        stage('Run JobB') {
            steps {
                script{
                    def ecs = [:]
                    def ecs_services = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']
                    for (int i = 0; i < ecs_services.size(); i++) {
                        def service = ecs_services[i]
                        ecs["${service}"] = build job: 'JobB' , parameters: [name: 'string1', value: 'foo']
                    }
                    ecs.failFast: true
                    parallel ecs
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass the ecs service name as parameter if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i understand what you are doing above, but when i try it out i get the below error

<code>
WorkflowScript: 2: Invalid argument for agent - '${any}' - must be map of config options or bare none. @ line 2, column 11.
       agent any
             ^

1 error 
</code>

Comment: Looks like your agent declaration block has problem. Could you update your question with the jenkinsfile you are using in order to figure out the error?
If you want to use any available agent to run your pipeline you can just use ```agent any``` no need of ```${any}```

Comment: I am using the same jenkins script as you pasted above, just added `agent any` and it throws that error.
I also tried using without `agent any` and it gave me an error like
`WorkflowScript: 1: Missing required section 'agent' @ line 1, column 1.`

Comment: ```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Run JobB') {
            steps {
                script{
                    def ecs_services = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']
                    for (int i = 0; i < ecs_services.size(); i++) {
                        def service = ecs_services[i]
                        ecs["${service}"] = build job: 'JobB' , parameters: [name: 'string1', value: 'foo']
                    }
                    failFast: true
                    parallel ecs
                }
            }
        }
    }
}  ```

Comment: I have updated my answer to include agent section as well. Give that a try. It would make things easier if you update your original question with the code snippet instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i updated with the block i used and even after adding the Block for 

             ``` agent {
            node {
                label "master"  //change this as per your agent label
            }
        } ```

I still get error

Comment: WorkflowScript: 2: Invalid argument for agent - '${{
        node {
            label "master"  //change this as per your agent label
        }
    }}' - must be map of config options or bare none. @ line 2, column 11.
       agent {
             ^

1 error

Comment: i do have a node named master

Comment: Can you try uninstall/installing grail and groovy plugins. Also update the version of jenkins and the groovy plugins installed.